# In GNU GRUB, I receive error: no loaded kernel. How do I load a kernel?

Tags: grub2, kernel

Whenever I type in 'boot' I get the error message, "no loaded kernel".
How do I boot normally again?

grub version 1.98
dual-booting ubuntu and windows

Answer (score 1):

Looking at various reports about this error which is related to the version of grub that comes with 9.10 Karmic Koala. The solution would be to burn a copy of 10.04 livecd and follow the steps detailed here [Ubuntu Grub Wiki Reinstalling from LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD) to repair your grub. Later if you are successful it would be advisable to update to 10.04 as it will be more stable in the long run than 9.10