# Ubuntu Crashed, Now, how to load kernel in GNU GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In GNU GRUB, I receive error: no loaded kernel. How do I load a kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29190/in-gnu-grub-i-receive-error-no-loaded-kernel-how-do-i-load-a-kernel)

I'm trying to load the kernel in 12.04's version of GUN GRUB.  When I type boot I get the "no loaded kernel" error.  I've tried recommended instructions of `search --set=root --file /vmlinuz` but I get the error:

> no such device: /vmlinuz

So...advice on how to set this and why I'm having trouble?  Also, I've burned the .iso for Boot-Repair but I don't know how to set it to boot.  I'm on a PC running Windows 7 AND Ubuntu 12.04. I can't get to the BIOS settings though and GRUB is a mystery to me.  Any Advice would be GREATLY appreciated.

Some other notes.  "find" isn't a recognized command in GRUB. When I search as follows: `search /vmlinuz` OR `search --file /vmlinuz` I get

> no such device:/vmlinuz

When I type `ls` I get:

```
(memdisk) (loop0) (hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

Comment: I'll take a closer look at that but I am not sure at this point that my problem is related to grub...

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created a Boot Repair CD, you computer should boot it automatically if it is in the computer at startup. If you computer doesn't boot it automatically, look on the BIOS screen for Boot Menu. Press the corresponding key (sometimes one of the F keys) at the BIOS screen. You will then be presented with a menu where you can select your CD drive (the name will usually be similar to what is written on the front of the CD drive the CD is in.

Comment: Your answer only elaborate part of the question. He actually wanted  to boot the old system. That part is absent in your answer.

Comment: So I was able to get the Boot Repair to run and it performed it's diagnostic, but even after it's finished I still can't boot.  The problem is exactly the same...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to use a SUPERGRUB CD in order to backup your grub loader
, this link will be helpful

[SUPERGRUB](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)